# Converting from ANSI to Unicode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, multibyte

I'm using Visual Studio .NET 2003, and I'm trying to convert a program written in purely ANSI characters to be independent of Unicode/Multi-byte characters.

The program has a callback function of pcap_loop, called "got_packet". It's defined as

```
void got_packet(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *cpacket)
{
   USES_CONVERSION;
   _TUCHAR *packet;
   packet = A2T(cpacket);
   ...
}
```

However, I get the error message

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const u_char *' to 'ATL::CA2WEX<>'
```

How do  fix this?

Comment: ANSI what? ANSI is a standards body, do you mean ASCII?

Comment: Well, I'm not too familiar with the exact terms, but I mean ANSI character string, as mentioned in the MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.71).aspx

Basically, the program used char, char *, unsigned char and unsigned char * for every character strings/arrays etc, and string functions such as strstr and strlen, with no attention paid to Unicode characters.

Comment: @paxdiablo: "ANSI" is also an alias for the Windows-1252 character set. http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: I would rather we call it Windows code page 1252 rather than a generic term like ANSI. But, since it's cleared up, I won't push the point :-) Thanks, @Aaron.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's a historical thing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 for an explanation. :-)

Comment: NO!! Assuming ANSI=CP-1252 is wrong. See http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/cs.htm : "the upper 128 is different for each ANSI character set"

Comment: ANSI has turned into a generic term for any 8-bit code page.  "Multi Byte Character Set" is the proper term.  ANSI rolls off the tongue a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that ATL doesn't know `u_char` so it can't select the correct convertion. Try this:

```
packet = A2T((char *)cpacket);
```

For more information, see

- http://writebettercode.org/2006/12/atl-70-string-conversion-classes.html
- [MultiByteToWideChar Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx)